# UIPageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController not called after once returned nil

Tags: ios, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement `UIPageViewController` with validation on every step. My code was working fine without validation, so everything with pages seems to be done right. This is my code:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    int index = [(MyViewController *) viewController index];
    index--;
    return [_viewModel viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    BOOL isDataValid = [(MyViewController *) viewController validateData];
    if (isDataValid) {
        int index = [(MyViewController *) viewController index];
        index++;
        return [_viewModel viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

My problem is that when step 1 is shown, `viewControllerAfterViewController` is called to prepare step 2, but because step 2 cannot be valid (user didn't have chance to input data) so it is returning nil. I would like `UIPageViewController` to call `viewControllerAfterViewController` every time user tries to swipe to the next screen and not give up after receiving a nil. Is it doable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UIPageViewController has an underlying cache.  You can reset it with

```
pageViewController.dataSource = nil;
pageViewController.dataSource = self;
```

You can call this once the page you are on becomes valid.

Comment: Worked! Not that easy to observe if content view of child view controller has become valid, but now it is working!

Comment: Where to call this method @Lou Franco

Comment: This did not work for me.  I executed the 2 lines in the viewDidAppear of the page that is displayed by the UIPageViewController, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue, I added the following code (Only calling add subview is not enough)

```
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[_viewCarouselContainer addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now both methods are getting called properly on respective swipes

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController ;

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController ;
```